# ORDER BY in QUERY functions of Google does not work at all

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Please consider this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIbyvtr2OpjD25OxeMjId1PbtVKmcI6V_KvCJqzs7U8/edit#gid=151995974

In the `TestSelect` Sheet, I've entered 2 `QUERY`formulas:

- in A1, I've entered this formula `=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B;"SELECT A,B")` and it works well
- in D1, I've added an `ORDER BY`criteria, like this `=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B;"SELECT A,B ORDER BY B")`

The second formula does not work at all. There's no syntax error but no result too. Have I made a mistake in my formula ? I've tried to add `DESC` or `ASC` after the column letter but it change nothing...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula works fine.

The issue is that **blank cells are counted first**.
You can find your rows with data in the end of the document.

**Exclude blank cells** to correct the view you by using the following formula.

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B;"select A,B where A<>'' order by B";1)
```

[image]